# Is the time complexity of this algorithm O(N^2)?

Tags: java, algorithm, foreach, time-complexity

Currently I'm learning about algorithm efficiency in terms of time and space complexity. 
I have this algorithm written in Java:

```
String[] remove = value.split(",");
String[] temp = (pb.get(key)).split(",");
String newval = "";

for (int i=0;i<remove.length;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<temp.length;j++){
        if (remove[i].equals(temp[j])){
           temp[j] = "";
        }
    }
}
for (String str : temp){
    if (!(str.isEmpty())){
        newval = newval + "," + str;
    }
}
newval = newval.substring(1, newval.length());
pb.put(key, newval);
```

From my understanding, the first loop (nested loop) would have a time complexity of O(N^2) and the second loop would be O(N). Am I correct? 
And how do I calculate for the space complexity ? 
 
Also, an unrelated question; how do I change the first loop into an enhanced for-loop ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yup thats right and space complexity is m+n assuming size of arrays is m & n respectively

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity : `O(N^2)` : You yourself told the answer. Also, `substring()` method is a linear time operation in Java 7.

Space complexity : `O(m+n)`
: As you are using two arrays having size lets say m and n.

To your other question, enhanced for loop can be used like below

```
for(String str1 : remove){
 for(String str2 : temp){
   if(str1.equals(str2)){
     //
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: how do I replace temp[j] in my for-loop so it would fit in the algorithm, since there is no pointer variable (which was int j) ?

Comment: Use it according to your requirement. If you want to use indexes. Then don't use enhanced for loop in the inner loop.

Comment: thanks for the answers! I just thought that it would look weird if I combine enhanced for loop and the normal for loop. Any thoughts on that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the time complexity is O(N^2) because of what you said: first loop's time complexity is O(N^2) and the second one is O(N) (you choose the worst (bigger) one). You have, still, to pay attention to all the methods you invoke like `subtring(...)` because one of them can have a bigger time complexity, what will change the overall time complexity.

Hope this helps you.